# Guice 3.0 - Purpose of Constructor Bindings?

Tags: java, guice

I've just read the chapter about [Constructor Bindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings) in Guice's User Guide but don't really understand when to use Constructor bindings.

As far as I understand, they provide the same functionality as @Provider methods, except instances created with Constructor Bindings participate in AOP. Is this correct? Can anyone give a better example than the one in the doc?

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I understand, they provide the same functionality as @Provider methods, except instances created with Constructor Bindings participate in AOP.

That's more or less correct, though there are some advantages that constructor binding has. Basically, it's a way of binding to a class as if it had an `@Inject` on a specific constructor even if it doesn't and you can't add the annotation yourself. Unlike `@Provides` methods, you could write utilities to allow you to do more interesting things. For instance, you could have a utilitiy method that returns the only constructor of a class, throwing an exception if there are more than one:

```
bind(Foo.class).toConstructor(getOnlyConstructor(FooImpl.class));
```

You could also use some other annotation (besides `@Inject`) if you wanted for some reason and have a utility method that gets the constructor that's annotated with that for binding.

Comment: It also addresses Guice's turkey bacon problem: http://tinyurl.com/turkeybaconproblem